# Trying to get Values between 2 dates but need start date and end date should be as given instead of as per database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get data between "Start" and "End" dates from database which is working fine and query giving me the result, Say
Start = 09-02-2022.
End   = 10-03-2022.
Database values start = "01-03-2022 to 09-03-2022" so i am getting result from date say 16-02 to 01-03.
But i want result should start with 09-02 and end with 10-03. If value is not present in database then it should give as "0"

Check attached Image for reference.

Code for Getting dates for last 30 days -

```
$getalldates = array();
             for($d = (Carbon::today()->subDays(30)); $d->lte(carbon::today()); $d->addDay()) 
                { $getalldates[] = $d->format('Y-m-d');}
```

Code for Getting data from database

```
$rahul = Buffalomilkrecord::select(DB::raw('date'), DB::raw('sum(totalmilk) as totalmilk, DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d") as "daykey"')) 
                                        ->whereBetween('date', [$olddate, $todaydate] )
                                        ->groupBy(DB::raw('date'))
                                        ->orderBy('date','asc')
                                        ->get()->pluck('date')->toArray();
```

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

This is what i tried

```
 $result = array();
                                        foreach($getalldates as $date){
                                               $totalmilk= Buffalomilkrecord::select(DB::raw('sum(totalmilk) as totalmilk'))->whereDate('date',$date)->pluck('totalmilk');
                                               if($totalmilk){
                                               $result[] = array($date =>$totalmilk);
                                               } else {
                                               $result[] = array($date =>0);
                                               }
                                                
                                        }
```

I am expecting

This is my output 0 => array:1 [▼ "2022-02-09" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#348 ▼ #items: array:1 [▼ 0 => null ] }
and i am expecting "2022-02-09" = "0"

Check Image
[image]

Comment: Why are you using pluck at the end?

Comment: Took me a while to understand but are you meaning you want it to show that there are 0 results for a certain day? e.g. 2022-02-26 => [], empty array?

Comment: Yes...  Thanks for reply.....check updated code where i get the out put but instead of zero its showing null.